# Saving multiple fields of a model instance using a for loop - Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm having a problem when trying to save data into an SQLite database from a Django View. Generally speaking, my approach is the following and it is intending to populate the instance inside a loop and finally save it.

1) Getting data (dict)
2) Instantiating the model
Loop - In
3) Loop over the dict to get the key, values pairs and saving them into the instance
Loop - Out
4) Saving the instance

The problem is that I'm getting an empty instance after the for loop instead of a populated one.
Now the code

**models.py**

```
class OptionsHomePage(models.Model):
    option_a = models.IntegerField(choices=MINUTES_OPTIONS) 
    option_b = models.IntegerField(choices=HOURS_OPTIONS) 

    start_time_am_minutes = models.IntegerField(choices=MINUTES_OPTIONS, default=0) 
    start_time_am_hours = models.IntegerField(choices=HOURS_OPTIONS, default=0) 
    end_time_am_minutes = models.IntegerField(choices=MINUTES_OPTIONS, default=0) 
    end_time_am_hours = models.IntegerField(choices=HOURS_OPTIONS, default= 0)
```

**Views** Note: synonyms is a dictionary where I'm mapping the data that comes from the front to their respective values in the model

```
...
        options = OptionsHomePage()
        data_to_fill = request.GET.get('data_to_fill')
        data_to_fill = json.loads(data_to_fill)
        for k, v in synonyms.items():
                try:
                    # print(data_to_fill[k])
                    data_name = synonyms[k]
                    value = data_to_fill[k]
                    options.data_name = value
                    print('{} - {} '.format(data_name,data_to_fill[k]))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        print(options)
        options.save() 
...
```

The print statements there, just for seeing what's happening there gives me the following:

```
end_time_pm_minutes - 10
delay_seconds - 11
screen_of_option - off
------------------------------
OptionsHomePage object (None)
------------------------------
```

Well... thanks in advance! If something is not well explained or shown just tell me and I can elaborate more!

Comment: You should save inside the loop

Comment: @Moha369 I've tried. If I save inside the loop the instance is not fully populated so it raises an Exception due to that... Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, you want to say `setattr(options, data_name, value)` instead of `options.data_name = value` :)

Comment: @Moha369 Worked perfectly!!! Thanks... Do I need to select your answer or something like that?

Comment: No need, glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work:

```
instance = ModelInstance()
allowed_fields = ['name', 'username' .... etc ]
for field, value in data_to_fill.items():
   if field in allowed_fields:
      setattr(instance, field, value)

instance.save()
```